# What is the difference between CURRENT and TODAY in Informix

Tags: date, informix, extend

I am junior in informix and I am struggling with some date calculations. I have this code snippet in my source:

```
LET dtRefDate = TODAY;

IF extend( CURRENT, hour to hour ) BETWEEN '06' AND '23'  THEN LET
   dtRefDate = TODAY+1;
END IF;
```

Can anybody explain me please what does extend function do? and what is the difference between CURRENT and TODAY? I didn't comprehend the difference from IBM official documentation. 
Thank you

Comment: Note that instead of using EXTEND, the code could simply request CURRENT HOUR TO HOUR and get the same result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

TODAY returns a DATE value, CURRENT returns a DATETIME (YEAR TO FRACTION (3)) value.

EXTEND is used to extract individual parts of a DATE or DATETIME value.

Look at this examples:

```
> select CURRENT from table(set{1});
(expression)
2019-09-29 10:07:12.000
1 row(s) retrieved.

> select TODAY from table(set{1});
(expression)
09/29/2019
1 row(s) retrieved.

> select extend(TODAY,year to year) from table(set{1});
(expression)
2019
1 row(s) retrieved.

> select extend(TODAY,month to day) from table(set{1});
(expression)
09-29
1 row(s) retrieved.

> select extend(CURRENT,hour to minute) from table(set{1});
(expression)
10:08
1 row(s) retrieved.

>
```